# rebase parent master branch in to forked branch in git

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, branching-and-merging

I have an original/parent git repo with master branch for example `https://github.ironman.com/ironman/jarvis.git`,

Now someone from my team has forked this repo and now the repo is `https://github.ironman.com/steve/jarvis.git`, where he has made many changes/commits to the repo

Now I had forked the above repo of my friend Steve and now the repo is `https://github.ironman.com/tony/jarvis.git`, here I have added additional functionality with a huge number of commits

In the meanwhile, the parent repo `ironman(https://github.ironman.com/ironman/jarvis.git)` has lot of branches merged in to it from some other team, so now my actual need is to merge this parent repo into my repo `tony(https://github.ironman.com/tony/jarvis.git)` with a single commit something like `rebase`

I have tried some ways from my repo(tony) master branch like below

```
git add remote upstream `https://github.ironman.com/ironman/jarvis.git`
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

But with the above steps, all the master branch commit history(nearly 400 commits) is updated on top of my current master branch, which I don't want because I will lose track on my current master branch commit history and then I tried using `rebase`

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i upstream/master
```

Here there is nearly 200 commit history difference between my branch and parent master branch, so with the above `rebase` command, it is asking/showing me merge conflicts for every single commit on the master branch. Hence I need to fix them individually for nearly 100 commits and run git rebase --continue 100 times which is really tedious job to do

So finally my question is how can I merge parent master(`ironman repo`) branch on top of my branch(`tony master branch`) with a single commit?

**Scenario:**

```
                     ironman
                        |
                      steve(forked from ironman)
                        |
                       tony(forked from steve)
```

I want to merge ironman master branch into tony master branch with a single commit on top of it

Comment: I think, unfortunately, that this is what happens when you let forks diverge for so long. My advice would be to make a cup of coffee and sit down for an hour or two and do the rebase, commit by commit =)

Comment: Use squash in interactive mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to sit through so many replays of commits in a lengthy rebase, then the obvious alternative would be to just do a merge instead:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

This would result in a single (merge) commit now sitting on top of your `local` version of `master`, corresponding to all the changes which have happened since the two master branches diverged.

If you really need to go the rebase route, then I don't think there is any avoiding those conflicts as the commits gets replayed one by one.

Comment: You could squash somewhere along the way so at least you would only have one commit at the end… but merging would be much easier for essentially the same result. Very +1 explanation.